# protobuf: .proto file not under source directory

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm new to protobuf. Following the official tutorial https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial, I downloaded the latest release and tried to run the example `examples/addressbook.proto`

Inside `addressbook.proto`, there is a line 
`import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";`,

so one would need to provide a source directory (the `-I=`) so as to import this.

My problem is that, in the downloaded release, I have `addressbook.proto` under `examples` while the needed `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto` is under `src`

When I do

`protoc examples/addressbook.proto --python_out=. -I=src`

I get an error

> examples/addressbook.proto: File does not reside within any path
>   specified using --proto_path (or -I)

I tried playing around with using `--proto_path` and got the same error.

The issue is solved when I manually move the `addresbook.proto` under `src`, so that the needed package and the .proto are both under the same dir (specified by `-I=src`).

However, I wonder if there is a solution when the **.proto** file and the other to-be-imported packages are under different directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
protoc examples/addressbook.proto --python_out=. -I=src -I=examples
```

When protoc is installed system-wide, it usually has `timestamp.proto` in the default include path and `-I` doesn't have to be specified. But when building from the source folder directly it doesn't know the path automatically.